# Wordpress PHP - Get Post Object before $wp_query is set

Tags: php, wordpress

my brain hurts, because I can't find the answer to my problem. I tried to determine the current requested post (or any other context) at a point where the wp_query and every other conntected global variable is not yet set. It's the following filter:

```
function pr_disable_plugin_routine($plugins) { ... }
add_filter( 'option_active_plugins', 'pr_disable_plugin_routine' );
```

So I need to get the current context without the help of most of the wordpress functions. And I can't find any help on how to handle it with pure PHP. Wordpress needs to setup its query too, so the data must be around somewhere. No global var except for $wpdb and the PHP system globals seem to be set. Please help me...

PS: I don't know why the query is not set at that time, maybe it's due to my plugin beeing in the "mu-plugins" for the action to be called early enough. But this still confuses me, as I thought at least one var needs to be set before the actions and filters...

Greetings

Comment: I dont know why, but it keeps deleting my first sentence, which is my salutation. Please feel greeted now. EDIT: I may attract those problems...

Comment: welcome to SO @ColdJackle. Sometimes unnecessary bits [like greetings](http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior) are edited out by the community. It happened to a lot of folks, myself included. The shortest possible questions are one of the goals it seems. [Read up on help](http://stackoverflow.com/help) if there's anything else causing scratches of the head.

Comment: @leftside Thanks Buddy, I just don't wanted to sound impolite or demanding when asking the community :)